# Open File in Editor programmatically: org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Editor could not be initialized

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

My goal is to write a JUnit Plug-in Test for my Eclipse Plugin. The Test shall open an existing project and open a file in my editor. The file's content type is associated with my Editor inside the `plugin.xml` file.

With the code snippet from the Wiki page [How do I open an editor progrmamatically](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F) I got this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    IProject project;
    try {
        URI locationURI = workspace.getRoot().getLocationURI();
        project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("/MyDemoProject");
        if (!project.exists()) {
            assert(false);
            return;
        }
        project.open(null); // maybe not necessary. No action of already open.
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        assert(false);
        return;
    }

    IFile file = project.getFile("/model/test/Adapter.grr");
    IFileStore fileStore;
    try {
        fileStore = EFS.getStore(file.getLocationURI());
        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
        IDE.openEditorOnFileStore( page, fileStore );
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can see that the method `IDE.openEditorOnFileStore()` is also called when the editor is opened inside a running eclipse. But in the JUnit Plug-in Test the call leads to an exception.

```
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Editor could not be initialized.
  at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3212)
  at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3221)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:353)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:340)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  ...
```

That means the call to `getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().run(false, true, runnable);` in `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor` fails. Inside the `run` method it is the call `doSetInput(input);` that throws a NullpointerException. At the end the Exception is thrown in the class `FileStoreFileBuffer`: the call to `create(EFS.getStore(URIUtil.toURI(getLocation())), monitor);` in the `create` method fails, probably because the location isn't correct (the debugger shows `/`).

I don't know why, because the path to my file is correct. I should mention that I'm using a custom FileStore implementation, which has a method `String getContent()` that helps me check if the file could be found and read.

I noticed that the call `page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), "myeditorID");` successfully returns a valid `EditorPart`. But I get an error message

> responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK (was 404)

I assume that I will need the fileStore variant because the files remain on a server which I access through a FileSystem implementation.

Comment: How do you initialize `workspace`?

Comment: @boot-and-bonnet `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();`

Comment: I ran the code in a my own non-test plugin, with dummy text file for `Adapter.grr`, and it did open a text editor. Do you have a special editor for `.grr`, or perhaps the test workspace is missing some config/projects?

Comment: The project isn't missing in the test workspace. Does it need a special config file?
I do use an editor, which is not doing much. It extends CEditor.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation that it should work in general. Then I think there could also be a problem with my FileStore implemenation.

Comment: I guess the editor opening internals check if the filetype is registered with a type of editor, otherwise it checks the content for text and opens a regular text editor? Just a guess though, I haven't checked the code.